# Heroku Django Admin returns 'FileNotFoundError at /admin/projects/project/add/'?

Tags: python, django, heroku

I am trying to setup a Django admin page to be able to update my project portfolio directly. Everything works fine until I click on the 'add project' button. Then I'm hit with an error:

[image: file not found]

I do not understand what it is looking for. Any insight would be helpful as I've tried searching google/stack and haven't found a similar issue with a solution. If you need more information, let me know and I'll update my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in the file path on your `django` models. try changing the

```
models.FilePathField(path='#fullpathtoyourphotosdirectory')
```